# Passing a `data.table` to c++ functions using `Rcpp` and/or `RcppArmadillo`

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp

Is there a way to pass a `data.table` objects to c++ functions using `Rcpp` and/or `RcppArmadillo` without manually transforming to `data.table` to a `data.frame`? In the example below `test_rcpp(X2)` and `test_arma(X2)` both fail with `c++ exception (unknown reason)`.

**R code**

```
X=data.frame(c(1:100),c(1:100))
X2=data.table(X)
test_rcpp(X)
test_rcpp(X2)
test_arma(X)
test_arma(X2)
```

**c++ functions**

```
NumericMatrix test_rcpp(NumericMatrix X) {
    return(X);
}

mat test_arma(mat X) {
    return(X);
}
```

Comment: Good, that's the way it is supposed to work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building on top of other answers, here is some example code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double do_stuff_with_a_data_table(DataFrame df){
    CharacterVector x = df["x"] ;
    NumericVector   y = df["y"] ;
    IntegerVector   z = df["v"] ;

    /* do whatever with x, y, v */
    double res = sum(y) ;
    return res ;
}
```

So, as Matthew says, this treats the `data.table` as a `data.frame` (aka a `Rcpp::DataFrame` in `Rcpp`).

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
    x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), 
    y=c(1,3,6), 
    v=1:9)
do_stuff_with_a_data_table( DT ) 
# [1] 30
```

This completely ignores the internals of the `data.table`.

Answer (score 10):

Try passing the `data.table` as a `DataFrame` rather than `NumericMatrix`.  It is a `data.frame` anyway, with the same structure, so you shouldn't need to convert it.

Answer (score 6):

[Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) sits on top of *native* R types encoded as SEXP.  This includes eg `data.frame` or `matrix`.

`data.table` is not native, it is an add-on. So someone who wants this (you?) has to write a converter, or provide funding for someone else to write one.

Comment: Can't he just pass it as a data.frame, rather than NumericMatrix?

Comment: Yes @MatthewDowle, a Rcpp::DataFrame shaddows an R data frame. Does `data.table` have a C api ?

Comment: @RomainFrancois.  Great.  Then in Rcpp he can treat the data.table exactly as you would a DataFrame.  It's an identical structure, just with an extra attribute here and there.  I haven't done anything special to provide a C api - should I?

Comment: To us, that is essentially a list of columns, so yes this should work.  It of course doesn't offer any `data.table` hotness at our end which I fear the OP may (naively) expect.

Comment: Having a C api would allow people to take advantage of `data.table` wizardry without going back to R syntax, perhaps providing a `DataTable` class. Not sure what would be involved, etc ... as I'm not familiar with the internals of `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks @RomainFrancois and Dirk. I can see lots of goodness here using as DataFrame in Rcpp already. Happy to investigate DataTable Rcpp class if anyone needs it ...

Comment: If there is indeed a need, why not. I guess this would be something additional as we would not want to depend on each other package. But a joint effort on a `RcppDataTable` package or whatever ..

Answer (score 3):

For reference, I think the good thing is to output a list from `rcpp` as `data.table` allow update via lists.

Here is a dummy example:

```
cCode <- 
    '
     DataFrame DT(DTi);
     NumericVector x = DT["x"];
     int N = x.size();
     LogicalVector b(N);
     NumericVector d(N);
     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
         b[i] = x[i]<=4;
         d[i] = x[i]+1.;
     }
     return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("b") = b, Rcpp::Named("d") = d);
    ';

require("data.table");
require("rcpp");
require("inline");
DT <- data.table(x=1:9,y=sample(letters,9)) #declare a data.table
modDataTable <- cxxfunction(signature(DTi="data.frame"), plugin="Rcpp", body=cCode)

DT_add <- modDataTable(DT)  #here we get the list
DT[, names(DT_add):=DT_add] #here we update by reference the data.table
```