# Transpose rows to columns and remove only NAs in resulting columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to write code to go from an input file of this type

```
dput(input)
c("A\t8213", "B\tAnytown", "C\tAAA", "D\t19", "E\t19", "F\tAny ID", 
"G\t0", "H\t0", "I\t0", "J\t0", "K\t0", "L\t0", "M\t0", "N\t0.048", 
"O\t0.303", "P\t31", "Q\t0", "R\t-0.114", "S\t0.377", "T\t-5.833"
)
```

to an output file of this type (once the code is verified for one file, then it will be used in a function to process hundreds of files):

```
dput(output)
c("A\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ\tK\tL\tM\tN\tO\tP\tQ\tR\tS\tT", 
"8213\tAnytown\tAAA\t19\t19\tAny  
ID\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0.048\t0.303\t31\t0\t-0.114\t0.377\t-5.833", 
"")
```

I only want the rows where there is no NA in each column.

This is the code that I have written thus far (I am thankful for many useful code snippets at StackOverflow and R help mailing lists for the following revised code)

```
library(data.table)
inputtmp <- data.table(read.table(textConnection(input), sep = "\t",     
stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
inputtmp[, id:=1:length(inputtmp[[1]])]
inputtmp <- dcast.data.table(inputtmp, id~V1, value.var="V2")
varcols <- colnames(inputtmp)
```

Questions:

1) Is there a better way to "transpose" the rows to columns so that other steps are not needed to remove the NAs?

2) If not, then how can I remove only the NAs from each column?

I have tried different revisions of code presented in the following 2 links, but nothing has worked in my case.

1) [Fastest way to drop rows with missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755547/fastest-way-to-drop-rows-with-missing-values)

and

2) [Apply over rows of data.table: find rows where a subset of columns are all NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077207/apply-over-rows-of-data-table-find-rows-where-a-subset-of-columns-are-all-na?rq=1)

Thank you.

Comment: What would an `NA` look like in your input file? A missing value altogether like `"A\t"` or something else?

Comment: The fastest way to drop rows with NA values that I know of is `data[complete.cases(data), ]`

Comment: Using the bit Richard gave you, you might just do a for loop like `for(i in 1:length(data[1,])){data[complete.cases(data),i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
input <- c("A\t8213", "B\tAnytown", "C\tAAA", "D\t19", "E\t19", "F\tAny ID", 
           "G\t0", "H\t0", "I\t0", "J\t0", "K\t0", "L\t0", "M\t0", "N\t0.048", 
           "O\t0.303", "P\t31", "Q\t0", "R\t-0.114", "S\t0.377", "T\t-5.833")
inputtmp <- read.table(textConnection(input), sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rownames(inputtmp) <- as.character(inputtmp[, 1])
inputtmp <- as.data.frame(t(inputtmp))
library(data.table)
inputtmp <- data.table(inputtmp[-1, ])
inputtmp
#       A       B   C  D  E      F G H I J K L M     N     O  P Q      R     S      T
# 1: 8213 Anytown AAA 19 19 Any ID 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.048 0.303 31 0 -0.114 0.377 -5.833
```